# The requested protocol has not been configured into the system, or no implementation for it exists

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, networking

The following statement

```
var socket = new Socket(ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Udp);
```

Got the following error on my computer.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.Net.Sockets.dll
The requested protocol has not been configured into the system, or no implementation for it exists
```

However, it works if I change the `ProtocolType` to `Tcp`?

I'm using Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019.

**Update:**
I changed the code to initialize the socket. Now it gets an exception on the line `socket.Bind(endPoint);`.

```
var host = Dns.GetHostName();
var ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(host).AddressList[0];
var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
try
{
    socket.Bind(endPoint);
    socket.Listen(100);
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
        mre.Reset();
        socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AccetCallBack), socket);
        mre.WaitOne();
    }
```

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced

Comment: If `AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork =>` `SocketType.Raw`. `ProtocolType.Tcp` supports `SocketType.Stream`.

Comment: I changed it to `new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)`. Now it gets new exception of "The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced"

Comment: Lol, that was my mistake. `ProtocolType.Udp` supports both `SocketType.Dgram` and `SocketType.Raw`, but I meant to write the former. What is the context of your app here?

Comment: I'm writing a socket server and client using UDP. The client will send some data to the server and echo back.

Comment: With a connection-less protocol, you do not listen for connections. Use the [ReceiveFrom()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receivefrom) method to receive any datagram. [SendTo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.sendto) to send.